# Why my firebase cloud function process never finished?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this function for testing sending notification to all users.

```
export const sendTestingNotification = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const message = "Hello world";
    const body = "This is body"
    const getAllUsersPromise = admin.database().ref('/users').once('value')
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: message,
        body: body
      }
    }

    return getAllUsersPromise.then(results => {
      var tokens : string[] = [];
      console.log("Child Snapshot count: ", results.numChildren())
      results.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        var instanceId = String(childData.instanceId)
        if (childData.instanceId != null) { tokens.push(instanceId); }
      })
      console.log('final tokens = ',tokens," notification= ",payload);

      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response2 => {
        console.log ("Done sending notification call. Entering callback.")
        const tokensToRemove : string[] = [];
        response2.results.forEach ((result, index) => {
          const error = result.error;
          if (error) {
            console.error('Failure sending notification to instance id = ', tokens[index], error);
          }
          else {
            console.log("Successfully send notification to ", tokens[index])
          }
        });

        return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
      })
      .catch(console.log.bind(console));
    })
    .catch(console.log.bind(console));

});
```

I have only one user in firebase database, and that one user has instanceId.

Here's the console log:

```
Child Snapshot count: 1
final tokens = [ 'eMZHr5WgHmU:APA91bEKg8wAS5qYMxuSJqn...
Done sending notification call. Entering callback.
Successfully send notification to eMZHr5WgHmU:APA91bEKg8wAS5qYMxuSJqn...
Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

What's left of my function execution so that it finishes properly? The browser that call the function never stops show loading indicator.

If I add a response.send before return Promise, the browser loading finished. But checking at the log showed me that the process still working and returned the "Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'" error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HTTP type functions, you need to send a response to the caller to terminate the function.  For all code paths in your function, you should be calling `response.send()` or something that will send that response.  Please [consult the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) for more information an examples.  In particular, read the section on [terminating a function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions).